# d3 doesnt produce any output

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data is very much in flare form except with few minor changes..

Its of following format:

```
[
  {"name":"topic_1","children":[{"name":"foo",size:1},{"name":"bar",size:2}]},
  {"name":"topic_2","children":[{"name":"foob",size:12},{"name":"bbar",size:2}]}
]
```

I am trying to make this visualization

```
    http://bl.ocks.org/4063530
```

Rest of the code is exactly the same

But its not working by which i mean that i dont see any visualization.

ANy suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No code, no help :( Please add some of your code or show your own example online

Comment: Hey @fraz , did the answer below resolve this?

Comment: @ChristopherHackett: yes. sorry .. forgot to accept the answer.. tht was the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no root node in your JSON file. It should look like ...

```
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
      {"name":"topic_1","children":[{"name":"foo","size":1},{"name":"bar","size":2}]},
      {"name":"topic_2","children":[{"name":"foob","size":12},{"name":"bbar","size":2}]}
    ]
}
```

---

**Alternately if you have only pasted an excerpt of your JSON file**

As the file is been loaded with an `XMLHttpRequest` it has to be over HTTP. If the file is local and not been served by a web server your data will never load and will be seeing `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///..... Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.` in the JavaScript console